# Configuring laser_filters parameters

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, laser-filters, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the LaserScanRangeFilter plugin of the laser_filters package, but I need to configure its parameters dynamically as I have to send the upper and lower thresholds from a remote device. My question is, how can I modify those parameters automatically? Is it possible to modify the .YAML file used to set the plugin up through C++ or Python nodes? Or do I have to write every parameter in the .launch file manually (and if so how could I write the tags corresponding to the actual plugin parameters)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285312/configuring-laser_filters-parameters/) by [JKaiser](https://answers.ros.org/users/33362/jkaiser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-03-13**:
How often do you need to change them? What is your remote device / how are you communicating your upper / lower bounds?

**Comment by [JKaiser](https://answers.ros.org/users/33362/jkaiser/) on 2018-03-14**:
Device is a samsung tablet with android communicating with ROS through rosbridge. I only need to change parameters each time I start the main program of the robot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think [#q10266](https://answers.ros.org/question/10266/dynamic-reconfigure-to-camerayaml-file/) is what you're looking for.

Read the documentation of [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) for more details.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JKaiser](https://answers.ros.org/users/33362/jkaiser/) on 2018-05-03**:
dynamic_reconfigure won't let me configure the laser_filter node...

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-05-04**:
Can you be more explicit ?
If you run `rosrun dynamic_reconfigure dynparam list` you don't have your node ?

**Comment by [JKaiser](https://answers.ros.org/users/33362/jkaiser/) on 2018-05-07**:
No, It doesn't appear. Only the base Laser node appears, and the parameters that can be configured don't help me at all. The Laser_Filters node isn't listed at all. In the end I had to change the way my system interacted with the LaserScan data.